# PyINIT not getting called

Tags: python, c++

In Visual Studio 2019, trying to run this tutorial
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/working-with-c-cpp-python-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019
Except I call my module twitc.

The code to init the module never gets called.

```
import twitc
```

works fine.
But when I try to call twitc.generate_twit_list(0.1) it says

```
module 'twitc' has no attribute 'generate_twit_list'
```

My code it like

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cmath>

const double e = 2.7182818284590452353602874713527;

double sinh_impl(double x) {
    return (1 - pow(e, (-2 * x))) / (2 * pow(e, -x));
}

double cosh_impl(double x) {
    return (1 + pow(e, (-2 * x))) / (2 * pow(e, -x));
}

PyObject* generate_twit_list_impl(PyObject*, PyObject* o) {
    double x = PyFloat_AsDouble(o);
    double tanh_x = sinh_impl(x) / cosh_impl(x);
    return PyFloat_FromDouble(tanh_x);
}

static PyMethodDef twitc_methods[] = {

    { "generate_twit_list", (PyCFunction)generate_twit_list_impl, METH_VARARGS, "Generate the twit list of inter tensor links as a cache." },
    { nullptr, nullptr, 0, nullptr }
};

static PyModuleDef twitc_module = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "twitc",
    "Provides some functions, but faster",
    0,
    twitc_methods
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_twitc() {
    printf("Init TWITC\n"); // THIS NEVER GETS CALLED
    return PyModule_Create(&twitc_module);
}
```

Any ideas why this is failing?

Answer (score 0):

Solved - I was not linking in the python37.lib
Now it works.